# Help identifying and finding a solution to what I think is a linear algebra problem.

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory

I encountered an interesting problem at work the other day that I believe is a linear algebra problem(I'm many years out of uni so apologies if this isn't the case). I'm not sure how to classify this type of problem so It's been difficult for me to google a solution to it. I'm hoping that by posting the problem statement here, someone can point me in the right direction to find a solution or can just straight up show me a solution. Here it goes:

---

Let's say that I'm categorizing some raccoons and placing them into buckets $(A, B, C, D)$ based on criteria on $3$ dimensions (age, height, weight). Bucket A is animals between age $(0,2)$, height $(0, 3)$, weight $( 12, 14)$ exactly, Bucket $B$ are animals between age $(0, 2)$, height $(4, 6)$, weight $(4, 16)$, etc... Let's say bucket $D$ are all of the animals with (age, height, weight) specifications NOT in bucket $A, B,$ or $C$. IF I wanted to calculate what these possibly disjoint buckets are in $D$, how would I go about finding this solution?

---

Thanks ahead of time to anyone who can help me out! I'm not a mathsy individual but am keen on learning more about how to go about solving for this type of problem.

Comment: "These possibly disjoint buckets" isn't very clear to me. Can you give an example of the answer to the sort of problem you'd like to solve? Like, in your example, name (an example of) what bucket C would be exactly and then what the final answer you'd want to get would be.

Comment: your ABC amount to three brick shapes. I suggest you get some cubic blocks; perhaps sugar cubes, see what is left when thee bricks are to be removed from a larger brick. There will not be a single formula that specifies D.

Comment: Unclear if this is *off-topic* or not, which is why I am commenting rather than answering.  I think that your categorization algorithm is bad.  In my opinion, if you have 3 attributes (i.e. dimensions) $A,B,C$ then you need three groups of buckets.  That is, you might let $A_1, A_2, A_3$ represent three distinct age ranges.  Similarly, you might have buckets $B_1, B_2, B_3$ for various height ranges, and $C_1, C_2, C_3$ for various weight ranges.   ...see next comment.

Comment: Then, you could assign each racoon an element $(n_1, n_2, n_3) \in \mathbb{Z^3}$ to signify that the racoon had been assigned to $A_{n_1}, B_{n_2}, C_{n_3}$. This alternate approach would have two advantages: [1] It would analogize well to the concept of 3-dimensional categorization [2] It would facilitate any plausible algebraic computations that you might want.

Comment: I think @WillJagy understands the problem visually. Basically, if I have a 3D space where (0 < x < 3, 1 < y < 2, 4 < z < 5), and I call that volume A, and B is everything not in A, I'd have 4 distinct ranges that describe B if we only care about the positive axes. I'm wondering if there's a mathematical way to extend this when we have different types of cubes like A that we are subtracting.. I realize there would be multiple solutions for the space. The sugar cube analogy is nice but obviously does not scale to the real-world scenario I'm thinking about(not raccoons).

Comment: Do you need the minimum number of bricks remaining? Or just *some* decomposition of the remainder into bricks?

Comment: @MarkS. some decomposition of the remainder into bricks. thanks!